# How to apply a defined function on pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a following function defined, which is working on 2d arrays. The `angle` function is calculating the angle between vectors.

While calling the function below, its taking in "directions" as the parameter, which is a 2d array (with 2 cols one with x vals and another with y vals).

Now `directions` was obtained by applying `np.diff()` function 2d array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import rdp

def angle(dir):
    """
    Returns the angles between vectors.

    Parameters:
    dir is a 2D-array of shape (N,M) representing N vectors in M-dimensional space.

    The return value is a 1D-array of values of shape (N-1,), with each value between 0 and pi.

    0 implies the vectors point in the same direction
    pi/2 implies the vectors are orthogonal
    pi implies the vectors point in opposite directions
    """
    dir2 = dir[1:]
    dir1 = dir[:-1]
    return np.arccos((dir1*dir2).sum(axis=1)/(np.sqrt((dir1**2).sum(axis=1)*(dir2**2).sum(axis=1))))

tolerance = 70
min_angle = np.pi*0.22

filename = os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/bla.data')
points = np.genfromtxt(filename).T
print(len(points))
x, y = points.T

# Use the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm to simplify the path
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm
# Python implementation: https://github.com/sebleier/RDP/
simplified = np.array(rdp.rdp(points.tolist(), tolerance))

print(len(simplified))
sx, sy = simplified.T

# compute the direction vectors on the simplified curve
directions = np.diff(simplified, axis=0)
theta = angle(directions)

# Select the index of the points with the greatest theta
# Large theta is associated with greatest change in direction.
idx = np.where(theta>min_angle)[0]+1
```

I want to implement the above code on a `pandas.DataFrame` with trajectory data.

Below is the sample `df`. `sx`, `sy` values belonging to the same `subid` are considered to be one trajectory, say row(0-3) are having the same `subid` as 2, and `id` as 11 is considered to be the points of on trajectory. Rows (4-6) is one trajectory and so one. Therefore, whenever the `subid` or `id` changes, separate trajectory data is found.

```
  id      subid     simplified_points     sx       sy
0 11      2         (3,4)                 3        4
1 11      2         (5,6)                 5        6
2 11      2         (7,8)                 7        8
3 11      2         (9,9)                 9        9
4 11      3         (10,12)               10       12
5 11      3         (12,14)               12       14
6 11      3         (13,15)               13       15
7 12      9         (18,20)               18       20
8 12      9         (22,24)               22       24
9 12      9         (25,27)               25       27
```

The above data frame has been obtained after already applying the rdp algorithm. The `simplified_points` further unzipped into two columns `sx` and `sy` are the result of rdp algo.

The problem lies in getting the `directions` for each of these trajectories and then subsequently getting `theta` and `idx`. Since the above code has been implemented only for one trajectory and that too on 2d array, I am unable to implement it for above pandas data frame.

Please suggest me a way to implement the above code for each trajectory data in a df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.apply()` to work on each `(id, subid)`, with something like:

**Code:**

```
def theta(group):
    dx = pd.Series(group.sx.diff(), name='dx')
    dy = pd.Series(group.sy.diff(), name='dy')
    theta = pd.Series(np.arctan2(dy, dx), name='theta')
    return pd.concat([dx, dy, theta], axis=1)

df2 = df.groupby(['id', 'subid']).apply(theta)
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    id      subid     simplified_points     sx       sy
    11      2         (3,4)                 3        4
    11      2         (5,6)                 5        6
    11      2         (7,8)                 7        8
    11      2         (9,9)                 9        9
    11      3         (10,12)               10       12
    11      3         (12,14)               12       14
    11      3         (13,15)               13       15
    12      9         (18,20)               18       20
    12      9         (22,24)               22       24
    12      9         (25,27)               25       27"""),
                 header=1)

df2 = df.groupby(['id', 'subid']).apply(theta)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df2.values, columns=df2.columns)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
   id  subid simplified_points  sx  sy   dx   dy     theta
0  11      2             (3,4)   3   4  NaN  NaN       NaN
1  11      2             (5,6)   5   6  2.0  2.0  0.785398
2  11      2             (7,8)   7   8  2.0  2.0  0.785398
3  11      2             (9,9)   9   9  2.0  1.0  0.463648
4  11      3           (10,12)  10  12  NaN  NaN       NaN
5  11      3           (12,14)  12  14  2.0  2.0  0.785398
6  11      3           (13,15)  13  15  1.0  1.0  0.785398
7  12      9           (18,20)  18  20  NaN  NaN       NaN
8  12      9           (22,24)  22  24  4.0  4.0  0.785398
9  12      9           (25,27)  25  27  3.0  3.0  0.785398
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much. I will try the code and update you on it. Thanks again.

Comment: I think theta values are not correct from what you suggested    theta = pd.Series(np.arctan2(dy, dx), name='theta')  In the ref code, in "angle" function is returning 
  np.arccos((dir1*dir2).sum(axis=1)/(np.sqrt((dir1**2).sum(axis=1)*(dir2**2).sum(axis=1))))  Is this ok ? Because dir1 and dir2 are having different indexing. Kindly please see into this

Comment: So feel free to do the calculation any way you like.  You gave no expected output for your sample set, And the vectorized function is working on vectors of undocumented dimensionality, so I had no way to understand or verify any results.  Thus you got arctan because I was just trying to show how to go about making the calculation and return the results.  Without a *much* clearer definition of the actual calculation being performed, I am afraid I am out of answers.